# how to use match function in angularJS to filter out an object with certain string value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, match

I'm trying to filter out any object with the fileName value of "foo"

here is what i have so far

```
          var main_item = [];
          var child_item = [];
          angular.forEach(item.files, function(value, key){             
            if(value.indicator === true && value.fileName.match("foo")) {
              main_item.push(value);
            } else {
              child_item.push(value);
            } 
          });
```

so if item.files.indicator is true and item.fileName matches "foo" then push to main_item array

Comment: try Array.prototype.filter()

Comment: You've defined `item` as an empty array and then two lines later you try to iterate over it. I don't think you're going to get the results you're expecting.

Comment: @Lex although i appreciate your sense of humor i think he might have posted some pseudecode, i might be wrong though

Comment: Exactly. The point is we don't know without a [MCVE].

Comment: yea fixed.......

Comment: I still don't understand what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`item.files.filter(function(file) {return file.fileName == "foo"})`

might be what your are looking for